# How to zip multiple directories into individual zip files

Tags: zip

I'm new to using the terminal and I found a post on here with the following code that would allow me to zip multiple directories into individual zip files but I only got it to work once.  The code is this:

```
for i in */; do zip ‐r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
```

but now when ever I use it I get the following error:

```
zip warning: name not matched:
```

and when I check the folder it creates a `-r.zip`  file.

Comment: Your command doesn't do `zip -r` but actually `zip M-bM-^@M-^Pr` that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like zip wants the zip file first:

```
for i in */; do zip "${i%/}.zip" -r "$i" ; done
```

Comment: I modded you up; please try to explain why you enclosed $i in {} for the benefit of the OP

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That is explained in the answer to the duplicate question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68490/33055)

Comment: @Anthon - the problem here is that OP's command contains non-printable characters and that's why it doesn't work. Copy/paste the command in the OPs post and pipe it to `cat -v`... So I don't think it's a duplicate of that one (but should be closed nonetheless as a dupe of other questions that deal with this kind of stuff).

Comment: @Anthon The problem about botched copy&pastes is very common here indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to the terminal, then it's likely you haven't learned the daunting but helpful world of man pages :D

If you do `man zip` at the command line the intended usage of zip is the following:

```
"Normally when an input pattern
              does not match a file the "name not matched" warning  is  issued
"

If zip is not able to read a file, it issues a warning  but  continues.
       See  the -MM option below for more on how zip handles patterns that are
       not matched and files that  are  not  readable.   If  some  files  were
       skipped, a warning is issued at the end of the zip operation noting how
       many files were read and how many skipped."
```

I would start by replacing your zip command with a an echo "${i%/}" and see what your output is. Somewhere a folder is causing an issue, either you are unable to access it or it's name is incorrect. Since you're just looking at folders in one directory you can use `find . -type d -readable` to compare against the directories you want to access to see if there is a folder that you do not actually have access to read.

related Unix Stack Exchange Answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529851/zip-command-not-working

["zip warning: name not matched" while compressing a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179451/zip-warning-name-not-matched-while-compressing-a-directory)